# Upload Image won't upload unless I add a specific line of code that I don't want

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

My code wont work unless I add this specific line of code, the one that has the comment next to it (Line 3). Does anyone have any open suggestions on what I should do? Because I don't wont `$_SESSION['username'] = "nameofuser"`;
:

Here is the link to the code: [sweettune.info/code.txt](http://sweettune.info/code.txt)

Using "`$_SESSION['username'] = "nameofuser";`" and deleting it, but if I delete it my image won't upload.

```
<?php
  session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = "nameofuser"; // Won't work unless this line of code is added
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","newkit","frtysk489","configurenow");
$q = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code as to what exactly you want.Maybe As you tell by removing the `$_SESSION['username'] = "nameofuser";` your code doesn't work.
I think Its problem with Session Handling.

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['username']` set somewhere else? Because you're using it in `$q = mysqli_query(...` - and if it is NOT set, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `$_SESSION['username'] = 'nameofuser';` then you will need to choose another **unique** column from your table (such as the record id) to identify the row to be updated.

The reason the database is not updated is because your query specifically asks `WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"`

`"UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"`

Without a unique identifier, the table row cannot be updated, your update will fail.